# What is the best approach to connect Flutter to MySQL database

Tags: c#, mysql, flutter

What is the best approach to connect Flutter to MySQL database, and is it secure to put my connection string on it, also what do I need to establish this method?

**Note I preferred to use C# as connection script.**

I try MySQL package1 but I find it's not secured.

Answer (score 1):

First create web services(REST is preferable) and deploy it in any web servers. And use that end point in your flutter app. because it is not advised to connect DBs directly from front end